# button for settings on notifications in Android lollipop

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Does anyone know how to put the button for settings on notifications in Android lollipop? As shown in the picture (http://s12.postimg.org/a4zs2kost/photo_2015_02_24_18_12_26.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Activity can include an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) with a category of [Notification.INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES) such as:

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```